# updating a list of objects within an observable using RxJS 6 and Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am provided with two REST APIs available called Product and Price.

The problem I am facing is when searching by product name.  The user will provide a "query", and the product API will return all products that match this name.   I then need to get this list, cycle through each item to get the sku, then call the price API to get the price info.

The methods I have for Product and Price are:

```
getProductListByQuery(query: string): Observable<Product[]> {
   return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productEndpoint + '/' + query);
}

getPriceBySku( sku: string): Observable<Price> {
   return this.http.get<Price>(this.priceEndpoint + '/' + sku);
}
```

The product object looks like this:

```
import { Price } from './inventory';

export class Product {
  sku: string;
  name: string;
  status: string;
  price: Price;  
}
```

I want to loop through all the products and update **price**.

I've tried playing around with forkJoin, mergeMap, switchMap, concatMap, and anything that I could find that I read up... but I think it comes down to that I just don't understand what I'm trying to do... which would explain why I don't understand the outcome.

My method looks something like:

```
getProductandPriceByQuery(query: string): Observable<Product[]> {
   return this.productService.getProductListByQuery( query ).pipe(
           //  I want to loop through each Product and add Price.
           //  I am just stumped.
}
```

Comment: how you get sku, i don't see your are querying with product id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a way of doing it:

```
  getProductandPriceByQuery(query: string): Observable<Product[]> {

    return this.productService.getProductListByQuery( query ).pipe(

      switchMap(products => {
        const productWithPriceObservables = products.map(product => { 
          return this.productService.getPriceBySku( product.sku )
            .pipe(
              map(price => Object.assign(product, {price: price}))
            );
        });
        return combineLatest(productWithPriceObservables);
      })

    )

 }
```

1. First I get the products.
2. I then use "switchMap" to say that I will jump to a new observable. "mergeMap" would also be a valid option here, depending on your use case.
3. For each product I query for the price, and I merge the price into the product with:

   ```
   map(price => Object.assign(product, {price: price}))
   ```
4. I use combineLatest to wait for all of the prices to be returned before returning everything.

Comment: Thank you very much.  There are some minor tweaks on my end I will need to do, but that is because I didn't provide the full code to you.   The fact that I can now see product with price in one object, that is exactly what I needed.   Now I will just study this code to grow my knowledge on the subject.